# What is an LCG (Living Card Games)?

Tags: terminology

What is an `LCG`?

I was looking at Lord of the Rings board games and came across [Lord Of The Rings: The Card Game](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1589949811).

I saw that all of the expansions were marked with `LCG`. I've done some Google searches, but there doesn't seem to be anything like a Wikipedia entry for `LCG`.

- Is `LCG` a genre?
- How does it compare to Magic (`CCG`)?
- Or Dominion (Deck Building)?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I believe that Living Card Games is a term used (and owned) by Fantasy Flight Games.

You can read about them on [their website](http://www.fantasyflightgames.com/edge_npm_sec.asp?eidm=14&esem=1).  The basic theory is that they release a core set and potentially endless expansion packs.  However unlike Magic: The Gathering and other collectible card games, each set (core or otherwise) comes complete in each pack.

This should keep the cost much less for LCG's.

Comment: By coincidence, I'd just read about this the other day, in a question about [asymmetrical living card games](http://boardgamegeek.com/thread/836423/what-is-an-asymmetrical-living-card-game).

Comment: Ah ok. So you don't have to buy packs and packs and packs to get the best deck?

Is it mandatory that everyone have the core set? Or the core set satisfies everyone (1-4 players, etc.)?

Comment: @ericf - the core set generally comes with enough for two players.  You only need more packs if you want more copies of cards.  Many of the expansion sets come with multiple copies of the cards as well.

Comment: @ire_and_curses that article really helped

Comment: @PatLudwig ok, I got it after reading that article. If you add the article link to the answer I will mark it as correct.